# How to create a pagination for dynamically created table layout using set visible?

Tags: android, pagination, android-tablelayout

I am getting data from server and create the tablelayout dynamically for that response, now I need to show only 5 rows per page, I am using `setvisible(view.invisible)` to hide all the table rows, How to set the 5 rows `setvisible(view.visible)` to show the rows like pagination ?

The code I used to create the table dynamically is below.

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablenew);
         TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
         tableRow.setId(1);
         tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
         tableRow.setPadding(0,0,1,1);
         tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams());
         tableRow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         TextView text = new TextView(this);
         text.setText(name);
         text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
         text.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         text.setTextSize(30);
         text.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams());
         final Button button = new Button(this);
         button.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         button.setTextSize(30);
         button.setTag(value);
         button.setText("Install");
         button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams());
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)        findViewById(R.id.tablenew);
                    final TableRow parent = (TableRow) v.getParent();
                    tableLayout.removeView(parent);
                          String id=(String) v.getTag();

                 }
          });//button click listener
         tableRow.addView(text);
         tableRow.addView(button);
         tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

Comment: what you gonna do? explain bit more

Comment: @MD -i need to show 5 rows per page with setvisible(view.visible) using row index programmatically.

Comment: @MD-initially i need to show the first 5 rows of the table using setvisible(view.visible), if the user click the next button, then need to invisible the visibled rows and make the next 5 rows visible.

Comment: please post your xml file here

Comment: @jayesh I'm creating table layout programmatically . not by xml file

Comment: @ Gopal Rao - Can you explain little bit more for me.I'm a newbie to Android.If possible give me some examples.

Comment: @Strawberry: then why you use findViewById for Table ??

Comment: @jayesh actually, i just created the table layout in the xml file and adding rows by programmatically using the above code.

Comment: @Strawberry: In this case you can first retrieve all data and make raws accordingly, i.e you have 20 set of data, now you create 20 raws then just display first five, then on button click set invisible for first five button and set visible for next five button

Comment: @jayesh i have retrieve all the data and created the row accordingly with setvisible(view.inivisible), please tell me how to get the first five rows from the table using the row index or row id and make them setvisible(view.visible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/), they have explained with example code..

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

tableraw.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablenew"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/next"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

TableViewDemo.java

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TableViewDemo extends Activity {

int index = 5;
Button nextButton;
TableLayout tableLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tableraw);
    tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablenew);
    nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setTag(i);
        tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        tableRow.setPadding(0, 0, 1, 1);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams());

        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("name" + i);
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        text.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        text.setTextSize(30);
        text.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams());

        final Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        button.setTextSize(30);
        button.setTag("value");
        button.setText("Install" + i);
        button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams());
        tableRow.addView(text);
        tableRow.addView(button);

        if (i < 6) {
            tableRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            tableRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

    }

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

                TableRow parent = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(i);
                // tableLayout.removeView(parent);
                Integer id = ((Integer) parent.getTag());
                if (id > index && id <= (index + 5)) {
                    parent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    parent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
            index = index + 5;

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: you most welcome.... :) but you can use pageview indicator instead.. its very good for pagination

Comment: Why don't you encourage to use `ListView`? `ListView` is efficient to handle memory when there are lot of rows to be shown...

Comment: @ jayesh Actually Im not aware about page view indicator ..How to use that for this concept.

Comment: @ Gopal Rao In List view only scrollable is available but pagination ?

Comment: you can download demo from this link https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 1):

```
         prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
           {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) 
                   {
                           TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablenew);
               for (int i = 10; i < tl.getChildCount(); i--)
               {

                   if(i>0)
                   {
                           TableRow row = (TableRow) tl.getChildAt(i);
                           Integer id = ((Integer) row.getTag());
                   if (id < 11 && id <= (10 - 5)) //index - 5)) {
                   {
                           Log.d("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii",Integer.toString(i));
                       row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   } 
                   else 
                   {
                           Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",Integer.toString(i));
                       row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   }
                   }

               }
               //index = index - 5;

           }
           });
```

Comment: @jayesh i have tried the previous button code like this but its not stop when the i reaches the value to 0, please suggest me..

Answer (score 1):

```
prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablenew);
            for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--)
            {
                Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",Integer.toString(index));
                TableRow row = (TableRow) tl.getChildAt(i);
                Integer id = ((Integer) row.getTag());

                if (id < index && id <= (index - 3)) //index - 3)) {
                {
                    Log.d("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii",Integer.toString(i));
                    row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",Integer.toString(i));
                    row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
            index = index - 3;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Tabledemo extends Activity {
int index = 5;
int i,preval,preival;
int nexval=1;
Button prev,next;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabledemo);
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pre);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nex);

    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablenew);
            for (i = preval ; i > preival; i--)
            {
                TableRow row = (TableRow) tl.getChildAt(i);
                Integer id = ((Integer) row.getTag());

                if (id < index && id <= (index - 5))
                {
                    row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    nexval=i;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
            preival=preival-5;
            index = index - 5;
        } 
    });


     next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablenew);
                for (i = nexval; i < tl.getChildCount() ; i++)
                {
                    TableRow row = (TableRow) tl.getChildAt(i);
                    Integer id = ((Integer) row.getTag());
                    if (id > index && id <= (index + 5)) 
                    {
                        row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        preval=i;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                preival=index;
                preival=preival-5;
                index = index + 5;
            }
        });
```